# Cannot run Wordpress on Mac without MAMP

Tags: wordpress, macos, apache

I am following [this](https://rohutech.com/how-to-install-wordpress-locally-on-a-mac-without-mamp/) to install Wordpress on Mac without MAMP.

Here are the lines that I changed for each of the following files

etc/Apache2/httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/amir/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/amir/Sites">
```

etc/Apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
#    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
# </VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/amir/Sites/wordpress"
    ServerName test.com
    <Directory /Users/amir/Sites/wordpress>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

etc/hosts

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1       test.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I have three folders in Sites folder which are wordpress, myphphadmin and localhost.
I installed MySQL.

When I try to access test.com, I run into **Site can't be reached** error message.
When I try to access 127.0.0.1, I run into the following
**Forbidden**
**You don't have permission to access this resource.**

Not sure where I should go from here and which part I got wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: not too familiar with Mac, but on windows User folders require special permissions, why don't you try creating a document root folder in another location

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question is about _installing/configuring_ wordpress, not _development_ (see [help/on-topic]). It fits better on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com or superuser

Comment: Sorry I have no answer to a MAMP set-up, but just curious if there is a reason why you need MAMP specifically? Local (https://localwp.com/) is a very easy to use local environment for WordPress if you're willing to try something new